# calling MPI of Fortran from python

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, ubuntu-18.04, f2py

I try to calling MPI of Fortran from python.

in helloworld.f90, I write:

```
subroutine sayhello(comm)
use mpi
!include 'mpif.h'
implicit none
integer :: comm, rank, size, ierr
call MPI_Comm_size(comm, size, ierr)
call MPI_Comm_rank(comm, rank, ierr)
print *, ’Hello, World! I am process ’,rank,’ of ’,size,’.’
end subroutine sayhello
```

And another one called *hello.py*:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import helloworld
fcomm = MPI.COMM_WORLD.py2f()
helloworld.sayhello(fcomm)
```

However, in the ubuntu 18.04, I use Python 3.7.4, I can not use the command to create file.so:

```
f2py -m helloworld -h helloworld.pyf helloworld.f90
f2py -c helloworld.pyf hello.py
```

When I run command:

```
mpirun.openmpi was unable to find the specified executable file, and 
therefore
    did not launch the job.  This error was first reported for process
    rank 0; it may have occurred for other processes as well.
```

Can you help me to fix this error or provide other command to run

My computer can openMP of Fortran from Python. Also, I can run MPI in Fortran . However, I can not call MPI of Fortran from Python.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: it looks like `f2py` cannot find the MPI include files. make sure the mpi devel package is installed, and add pass the path to the include files on the `f2py` command line.

Comment: I used to run MPI successful with fortran. To run MPI. I installed openMPI for C/C++/Fortran, and mpi4pi for PYTHON .Can you give me example a command that includes the path as you mentioned.

Comment: `f2py -I/path/to/include ...`

Comment: if your MPI code is only in Fortran (that is, no MPI communication is done in your Python) then you should not need to use mpi4py in Python at all. Just call your Fortran code from inside Python as if it is serial code, but invoke mpiexec on the command line when running the Python script. Don't forget to initialize MPI inside Fortran code. This way you won't need the MPI library to be recognized by Python, and that should potentially resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to make some comments about this issue. I create the Python module in Ubuntu 18.04. Actually, it is a WSL (Windows sub system). I run with openMPI 1.10.7 (is too old), but it is the version that I have. My tests were made using numpy 1.16.5 and Python 2.7.15.

1) I have created a Python module using your source codes through the following command  from [mpi4py](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) doc page

```
f2py --f90exec=mpif90 -c helloworld.f90 -m helloworld
```

as said by Gilles you need to link the mpi, but you can use the flag `--f90exec` as shown above. This flag tells to f2py which F90 compiler you want to use. The [f2pydoc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/f2py/usage.html) has a complete list of f2py flags that will help you to create Python modules from Fortran codes. After the Python module generation you can run your script.

Another way to do it is like you did. However, I think that your second command is wrong. You do not use the flag `--f90exec` in the second command. Moreover, you have used the signature files with the name of your Python script in order to create the module. You should replace the Python script by the Fortran filename.

2) I tested what you have done. Then, when I tried to import the module in the Python interpreter a n exceptionwas raised. To sum up, in order to create a Python module using `.pyf` files type

```
f2py -m helloworld -h helloworld.pyf helloworld.f90
```

and then

```
f2py --f90exec=mpif90 -c helloworld.pyf helloworld.f90
```

3) King said that you do not need mpi4py. However, I tested using without mpi4py and did not work, even doing all the MPI initialization process inside a FORTRAN subroutine. Below, one can see the codes that I used to make this test.

helloworld.f90

```
subroutine sayhello
use mpi
implicit none

! include 'mpif.h'

    integer :: comm, rank, size, ierr, namelength
    character(len=15) :: processorname

call MPI_INIT(ierr)
call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierr)
call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)
call MPI_GET_PROCESSOR_NAME(processorName, namelength, ierr)
print *, 'Hello, World! I am process ',rank,' of ',size,'.'

end subroutine sayhello
```

hello.py

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import helloworld

helloworld.sayhello()
```

4) If you want to create a module for Python 3.x scripts you can use similar commands, you just have to substitute `f2py` by `f2py3` or `python3 -m numpy.f2py` in the commands above.